# Java + SSL using custom Socket

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I'm developing a Java based P2P application where the peers are communicating with each using a library called ice4j and it's custom socket called PsuedoTCPSocket.

I now want to add SSL support to the application. PsuedoTCPSocket extends java.net.Socket so think it should possible to just use a SSLSocket on top of that socket. However I'm not able to find any way to create SSLSocket-instances using a custom underlying Socket. Is this possible and if so how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `PseudoTCPSocket` extends `java.net.Socket` (and doesn't break its API), you should be able to upgrade it to an `SSLSocket` using [`SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Thanks that looks like a great option! However, I can't find the corresponding function for SSLServerSockets. SSLServerSocketFactory doesn't seem to have any createServerSocket function that enables you to give it a custom Socket. Am I supposed to use SSLSocket at both peers or am I missing something?

Comment: `SSLSocket` are not in server or client mode until the handshake. Use `SSLSocket.setUseClientMode(false)` on the server before the handshake if you want a server socket.